# Trying to use HttpContext.Session in a static method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following method that gives the error

An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'HttpContext.Session'

```
namespace Website.Controllers
{

  // CONTROLLER CLASS IS HERE BUT REMOVED AS NOT RELEVANT CODE

  public static class HtmlExtensions
  {
    public static decimal GetCartTotal()
    {
      decimal cartTotal = 0;

      var storedData = HttpContext.Session.GetString(ShoppingCartTotal);

      if (storedData != null)
      {
        cartTotal = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<decimal>(storedData);
      }

      return cartTotal;
    }
  }
}
```

Obviously I understand I am calling a non static call from a static method, but I am not sure how to create an HttpContext.Session object. I need the method to be static as I am calling that data from the view. I can not pass the data in the view model as the data is being used on the _Layout.cshtml page and I do not want to go in and manually add it to every viewmodel and assign it in each controller method... What is the best way to call a method in the controller in a shared view?

I have the following in the View that works, but only when it is a static method, which because it is a static method that HttpContext is not working

```
@using Website.Controllers

@{
  var ShoppingCartTotal = HtmlExtensions.GetCartTotal();
}
```

Comment: HttpContext.Current is your friend. But use it wisely, don't put it in places where there couldn't be logically an HttpContext. I would think if it's intended for consumption in Razor you'd be fine though.

Comment: Another option is to use a BaseController that all relevant controllers inherit from so you can put shared resources in a single place to be accessed by multiple actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be passing the dependencies of the method from the caller, better would be to add a parameter in the method that takes `Session` object input and the caller would need to pass it in :

```
public static decimal GetCartTotal(HttpSessionState session)
{
  decimal cartTotal = 0;

  var storedData = session.GetString(ShoppingCartTotal);

  if (storedData != null)
  {
    cartTotal = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<decimal>(storedData);
  }

  return cartTotal;
}
```

Hope it helps!

### @Edit:

As suggested in comments by @Scott, you could make an extension method as well, as you already have it in a static class you could write it like:

```
public static decimal GetCartTotal(this HttpSessionState session)
{
      decimal cartTotal = 0;

      var storedData = session.GetString(ShoppingCartTotal);

      if (storedData != null)
      {
        cartTotal = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<decimal>(storedData);
      }

      return cartTotal;
}
```

and now you can call it at calling side like:

```
var total = HttpContext.Session.GetCartTotal()
```

Comment: You could even make it a extension method so you could do `var ShoppingCartTotal = HttpContext.Session.GetCartTotal();` from the razor view. (btw, I fixed the type that was being passed in to the function to the correct type)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain yeah, added that in the post as well