# Get a string from Session in Base Controller static method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to write a method in my BaseController like this:

```
public static string GetMyString()
{
    return HttpContext.Current.Session?["WebStringValue"]?.ToString();
}
```

If there is a value there, give me the value. If not return null.

My problem is that VS and the compiler are telling me:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Controller.HttpContext'

What am I missing?

Comment: `HttpContext` isn't static. Meaning your method cannot be static.

Comment: Your error is pretty self-explanatory.  You have a static method (remember static means **it does not need an instance of the class to be called**). Inside that static method you are accessing something that is an **instance member** (meaning you **must have an instance of the class to access this property**)

Comment: Try using the full qualification: `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["WebStringValue"]?.ToString();`. There is a non-static `HttpContext` property in the controller, I think that's why it's acting up

Comment: Why is the method static to begin with?  Why not use the non-static Session property in a non-static method?

Comment: have a look : https://stackoverflow.com/a/44444348/1875256

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the controller is defining [a non-static `HttpContext` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.httpcontext(v=vs.118).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Because you are missing the proper `using`, the compiler thinks you're trying to call that property (instead of [the static `HttpContext.Current` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.current(v=vs.110).aspx)).

To fix the error, use the full type name to invoke the property:

```
return System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session?["WebStringValue"]?.ToString();
```